# Angular 2+ custom validator "required if" another field is filled in

Tags: angular, validation, typescript, angular2-forms

I'm trying to create a custom validator for a template driven form where if one field is filled in another becomes required, but if the first field is empty the second isn't needed either.

Following the (typescript) examples in the docs to build a custom validator directive I can get that running on a field, and pass it the name of another one. Now here are my questions...

If a value is entered in field one and I check that field 2 is empty, how do I set "invalid" on field 2? (I realize I have access to its AbstractControl).

If I've set "invalid" on field 2 myself, do I need a separate validator on field 2 to remove its invalid status when it's filled in?

Or should I add the built in "required" validator on field 2 when the validator for field one is triggered (and if so how)?

Many thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you are after without a custom validator.

The code below is from a template driven form - binding the `required` validator directive on the second field to the `ngModel` value from the first field. So here you've got conditional validation applied to the second field, when the first field has a value.

```
First: <input type="text" name="first" [(ngModel)]="theFirst" #first="ngModel" >

Second: <input type="text" ngModel [required]="theFirst ? true : null " #second="ngModel" name="second"/>

<div *ngIf="second.errors">
  <span [hidden]="!second.errors.required">Second is required</span>
</div>
```

Further discussion on conditional validation bindings is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5976).

Comment: You could also skip the [hidden] part by placing the condition inside the div: <div *ngIf="second.errors.required"><span>Second is required</span></div>

Comment: @danpop Yes that's correct - I think I was referencing the [Angular Template Forms doco](https://angular.io/guide/forms) when I answered this - here they use `[hidden]` rather than removing the element from the dom.